# How i can add an ad-hoc attachment control inside my screen and get the attachment content and add it as an attachment inside a list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have a screen , where the user enter a number and attach a file >> now i want to get the item which have the related ID >> and get the attachment content >> and add the attachment as attachment inside the list item?

Can anyone advice?

Here is what i did, where i added an Input text + Add Picture media:-

[image]

and the following formulas inside the button:-

```
// Get the entered ID
Set(
    enteredID,
    TextInput1.Text
);



Set(
        selectedItem,
        LookUp(test1231, ID = Value(enteredID))
    )
;

// Check if a list item is found

        Patch(
            test1231,selectedItem,

            {
                Title:selectedItem.Title,
                Attachments: UploadedImage2
                
            }
        );
```

but when i click on the button >> no attachment will get added to the list item